Finding all the sides and diagonals of a parallelogram from a particular triangle inscribed within it
I have this parallelogram where M and N are midpoints. I was given that $\angle NAM = 30^\circ,$ $AN=9\sqrt3$ and $AM = 18$.

From this I found every detail about the triangle, $MN = 9$, $\angle MNA=90^\circ$, and all. Now I don't understand how to move on, how to link the triangle with parallelogram and get sides from this information.

sizes are the lengths, I believe my sketch should be fine


$$
\begin{aligned}
BM &= CM \\
CN &= ND \\
\end{aligned}
\quad\Rightarrow\quad 
KH = CH = \frac{1}{2}AK
\quad\Rightarrow\quad 
KH = CH = \frac{1}{3}AH
$$
I believe that you know the next steps... ($H$ is the midpoint of $MN$)

It becomes simpler if you start from the triangle $AMN$: $AM=18, AN=9\sqrt 3=\frac {\sqrt 3} 2 AM$, so $MN = \frac 1 2 AM = 9$.
Here is a Geogebra figure:

$M$ is the midpoint of $BC$ and $N$ is the midpoint of $CD$, so $MN$ and $BD$ are on parallel lines and $BD = 2MN$.
When we project everything on the x-axis, we immediately get $x_B=x_D = \frac 2 3 x_M = 6\sqrt 3$ and $x_C = 2\times x_B = 12\sqrt 3$.
The projection on y-axis gives $y_C = \frac 2 3 y_M = 6$, $y_B = 2 y_C = 12$ and
$y_D = -y_C = -6$.
It is now trivial to compute the sides of the parallelogram:
$AB = \sqrt{x_B^2 +{y^2_B}} = \sqrt{108+144}=\sqrt{252} = 6\sqrt 7$,
$AD = \sqrt{x_D^2+y_D^2}=\sqrt{108+36} = \sqrt{144} = 12$
Now for the diagonals:
$BD = y_B-y_D = 12 -(-6) = 18$, $AC=\sqrt{x_C^2+y_C^2} = \sqrt{432+36}
= \sqrt{468} = 6\sqrt{13}$.

Let $AD=BC=a, AB=CD=b, AC=e, BD=f$
$f=BD=2MN=18$ (Midpoint Theorem, $BM=CM$ and $CN=DN$)
$2\times AM^2 = b^2 + e^2 - \frac{a^2}{2}$  In $\triangle ABC$ (Median Theorem)
$2\times 18^2 = b^2 + e^2 - \frac{a^2}{2}$
and
$2\times AN^2 = a^2 + e^2 - \frac{b^2}{2}$  In $\triangle ADC$ (Median Theorem)
$2\times (9\sqrt3)^2 = a^2 + e^2 - \frac{b^2}{2}$
then
$a^2 + b^2 = 2268 - 4e^2$
Since In a parallelogram $e^{2}+f^{2}=2(a^2 + b^2)$,
$e^{2}+18^{2}=2(2268 - 4e^2)$
$e=6\sqrt{13}$
$2\times 18^2 = b^2 + (6\sqrt{13})^2 - \frac{a^2}{2}$,
$180 = b^2  - \frac{a^2}{2}$
and
$2\times (9\sqrt3)^2 = a^2 + (6\sqrt{13})^2 - \frac{b^2}{2}$
$18 = a^2  - \frac{b^2}{2}$
then
$a=12, b=6\sqrt7$
